# What governments do each civilization prefer and dislike?

Tags: civilization-3

In *Civilization 3*, what governments do each civilization like and dislike?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't copy out all the information at the moment, but the answers can be found [here](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ3/civilizations)